# How do you create boxes like github's explore section?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, github, background

Im looking for **Java Script** or **Css** to create random background but I don't know how!

[Explore page link](https://github.com/explore)

Comment: Did you try anything? Please post  your code..

Comment: no i don't try anything but find [http://qrohlf.com/trianglify/] [http://trigons.net/#welcome]

Comment: i need [http://oi60.tinypic.com/wkql1h.jpg] but searching for this but i can't find nice script ,this script  [qrohlf.com/trianglify/] have one effect but i need more.

Comment: What you want exactly ?‌ a snippet code of java script to generate random background for your boxes ?‌pls ask your question clearly dude :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look on this library: https://github.com/btmills/geopattern

This is a JavaScript port of [jasonlong/geo_pattern](https://github.com/jasonlong/geo_pattern) with a [live preview page](http://btmills.github.io/geopattern/) and is derived from the background generator originally used for GitHub Guides.

**Usage**

Include the minified script. jQuery is optional.

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script> <!-- optional -->
<script src="js/geopattern.min.js"></script>
```

Use either the GeoPattern browser global or the jQuery plugin:

```
// Use the global...
var pattern = GeoPattern.generate('GitHub');
$('#geopattern').css('background-image', pattern.toDataUrl());

// ...or the plugin
$('#geopattern').geopattern('GitHub');
```